# Python/BeautifulSoup - Can't match a tag containing specific text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've read tons of articles on stackoverflow about the same problem but no one is working for me.

Tag I need to select:

```
<p class="line">Actors: <a href="somelink">Actor 1</a></p>
```

The page is full of `p` tags with `class="line"` so I'm trying to match it by looking for the ones that contains the string "Actors: ":

```
data.find('p', attrs={'class':'line'}, text=re.compile(r'^Actors: $'))
```

This doesn't match anything. What would be the right syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it can be done with a single expression.

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s="""
    <p class="line">Actors: <a href="somelink">Actor 1</a></p>
    <p class="line">Other: <a href="somelink">Stunt 0</a></p>
    <p class="line">Actors: <a href="somelink">Actor 3</a></p>
    <p class="role-line">Actors: <a href="somelink">Actor 4</a></p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')
```

This work:

```
soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'line'})
```

This too:

```
soup.findAll(string=re.compile(r'^Actors'))
```

But both combined doesn't work, bug or unsupported, I don't know:

```
soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'line'}, string=re.compile(r'^Actors'))
```

But you have alternatives.

Using `set` intersection:

```
set([node.parent for node in soup.findAll(string=re.compile(r'^Actors'))]) & 
set(soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'line'}))
```

Result:

```
{<p class="line">Actors: <a href="somelink">Actor 3</a></p>,
 <p class="line">Actors: <a href="somelink">Actor 1</a></p>}
```

Using `findParents`:

```
[node.findParents('p', class_='line') for node in \
soup.findAll(string=re.compile(r'^Actors'))]
```

Result: (needs some filtering)

```
[[<p class="line">Actors: <a href="somelink">Actor 1</a></p>],
 [<p class="line">Actors: <a href="somelink">Actor 3</a></p>],
 []]
```

Using loops and conditions:

```
for p in [node.parent for node in soup.findAll(text=re.compile(r'^Actors'))]:
    if not 'line' in p.attrs['class']:
        continue
    print(p)
```

Result:

```
<p class="line">Actors: <a href="somelink">Actor 1</a></p>
<p class="line">Actors: <a href="somelink">Actor 3</a></p>
```

Note: `string` is the new `text` parameter in BeautifulSoup 4.4+

Answer (score 1):

```
html = '''<p class="line">Actors: <a href="somelink">Actor 1</a></p>'''
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
soup.p.text
```

out:

```
'Actors: Actor 1'
```

`p` tag has multiple text field.

```
soup.find('p', attrs={'class':'line'}, string=None)
soup.find('p', attrs={'class':'line'}, text=None)
```

out:

```
<p class="line">Actors: <a href="somelink">Actor 1</a></p>
```

The reason why `text/string=None` will match the `p` tag is:

when we use `text/string` in the `find()` as a filter, it's use `p.string` to get the string of `p` tag, and p tag has multiple text fields

> If a tag contains more than one thing, then it’s not clear what
>   .string should refer to, so .string is defined to be None

But you can find the text first, and get the element before the text:

```
soup.find(text='Actors: ').previous_element
```

in this case, `find()` only contains text filter, it will act like `find` in the text editor.

Comment: Yes, the text would be "Actors: Actor 1". I need to select the p tag which text contains the string "Actors: " since the p doesn't have an id or an unique class.

Comment: In your example you don't pass the condition that the text MUST contain the string "Actors: ". In the page there are a lot of similar p tags like <p class="line">Movies: <a href="somelink">Movie 1</a></p> but I want to match only the one for Actors

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of confusion with this too!

```
soup.findAll('p', {'class': 'line'}, text='Actors: ')
```

That should return the right thing? I believe you can also replace the class for ID?.

Hope that works. Did on my test.